# Error using WCF Service Reference using simplified configuration

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wcf-endpoint

I'm building my first WCF web service using .net 4.5.1(a web site...not an application).  When I test on my local machine I can add the service reference to a project and actually use the methods. No errors at all.

I've configured the site using the "Simplified" configuration

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <!--<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>-->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

After publishing the site to Azure I can add the service reference and it all appears to work fine.  I can see that my methods are available in my service client object.  When I test the program that uses one of the methods I get this error saying I have multiple endpoints and that I need to call them by name:

> An endpoint configuration section for contract
>   'ServiceReference1.IService' could not be loaded because more than one
>   endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate
>   the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

This is the offending line of code:

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient mysrv = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
```

It sounds like I've got to add an endpoint name:

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient mysrv = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient("my-endpoint-name");
```

Since the simplified configuration creates the endpoint names automatically I don't know what name to use.  I can't find any code samples showing how this is done.

Any help would be much appreciated,

James

Comment: With the simplified configuration you don't use endpoint entries.  Thats the whole point of using the "simplified" configuration. [simplified configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530014(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that.